# dell xps 15 webcam does not connect

Tags: webcam, camera

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 on virtual machine VMplayer.
I cannot connect my laptop camera.
The result of `lsusb` is as follows.

[image]

I installed cheese and ffmpeg and GTK UCV video viewer but failed to solve the problem.

Comment: You camera, as well as other devices, is in use by the host. In the virtualization software you're using there may be an option to disconnect USB devices from the host and use it in the guest.

Comment: appericiated! I did Thank you so much. I just check player -> removable device -> webacam -> connet.